# Nginx Module http_stub_status_module loading issue after installation

Tags: nginx

i am using nginx on one of my server, i download its source and compile it using:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module \
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log  \
--add-module=/opt/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module \
--with-http_stub_status_module
```

setup and add files in conf.d and its working ok. but suddenly when i restart it its giving me error msg:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "stub_status" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/mytest.conf:6
```

i looked into more details and find out it was unable to load the module "http_stub_status_module". i know i compiled it with installation.

> > > > My Question is there any way i can reload this module or add somewhere in conf to make it working??**i dont want to install it again because if i compiled it again it will remove my current configuration.

Answer (score 5):

You need to compile nginx with stub_status, pass the following to your ./configure file:

`--with-http_stub_status_module to ./configure`

Gentoo users: enable the [expanded USE-Flag](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Nginx#Expanded_USE_flags) `status` and recompile nginx. Example of /etc/portage/package.use/nginx:

`www-servers/nginx NGINX_MODULES_HTTP: stub_status`

Finally, do this: `emerge -pav nginx`

Answer (score 3):

Unlike other software such as Apache, Nginx has no mechanism for loading modules at runtime; they have to be compiled in.

If you run `nginx -V` on the old version before building a new one, you will get a message that includes the `configure` command it was built with.  Try using the same one in your new source tree; if you don't actually have the modules you need available, it will fail at that point. If both the configure with the same command and the subsequent build succeed, you should be reasonably confident that your new build has the same functionality as the old.  Of course you still have to watch out for any breaking changes that might have been made to nginx itself or any of those modules..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you probably have more than one nginx binary on your system, and now trying to load that one without the module. It's a common situation when someone compiles something himself from sources after installing through a package manager.

Comment: That is horrible advice, and completely wrong.


That does not mean you should not pay attention when building stuff yourself, and also, most of the time, distro package managers are to be preferred.